# How to fix "Range" of object "_global" error in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and am try to set up a macro, that searches for highlighted cells, gets their cell address' and highlights cells a specified number of rows away from the the original highlighted cell. I have tried to create a loop where I cycle through each of the highlighted cells in the column(For now I am just putting each of these values in an array instead of highlighting the required cells to test if the loop works) but I am getting the error mentioned in the title of this question, Haven't been able to figure out why this is happening, would be grateful for your help in figuring out this error. 
Thank you

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim start As Range
Set start = Range("A1")
Dim address As Range
Do While counter < 2

Application.FindFormat.Clear
Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
Set cell = Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchFormat:=True, after:=start)`



Set address = Range(cell.address)

 Set start = Range(address)



If cell.Value = (28 / 1 / 2013) Then

 counter = counter + 1

End If


ReDim Preserve arr(i)
arr(i) = cell.Value
i = i + 1
```

Comment: Why not specify the date as the "what" parameter"? Your current comparison is invalid.

Comment: The date I specified is only the first highlighted value in the column, I specified it as a condition to ensure that the loop does not continue indefinitely and stops at the last highlighted value in the column. All the highlighted cells are of the RGB colour in the code

Comment: So the date is irrelevant? Which line errors?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying the errors are shown the Set start = Range(address) and the Set address = Range(cell.address) code lines.

Comment: Your code is probably not finding the format and hence `Cell` is Nothing and you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

This should start you off.

You will need to add a check that you are not finding the same cell multiple times.

```
Sub x()

Dim cell As Range
Dim start As Range
Dim counter As Long, i As Long, arr()

Application.FindFormat.Clear
Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)

Set start = Range("A1")

Do While counter < 2
    Set cell = Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchFormat:=True, after:=start)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(i)
        arr(i) = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
        counter = counter + 1
        Set start = cell
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```